# Why is there a vii˚6 of III but no vii˚ of III in the minor mode?

Tags: functional-harmony

When tonicizing the mediant chord in the minor mode, you often use VII which acts as a secondary dominant of III and is very useful in tonicizing III if you are in the minor mode. Another option is to use vii˚6 of III which is the ii˚6 chord built on ^4. This would be vii˚6 of III. I can't really seem to find anything about the vii˚ of III. Is this a common chord to tonicize III or would you normally use a vii˚7 chord for this? I haven't learned vii˚7 chords yet but from what I understand, these are a direct replacement for V65 and would be built on the leading tone of the chord you are trying to tonicize.

Comment: Are you asking about how it would be labeled in Roman numerals, or are you saying you have not seen the chord in real scores?

Comment: 1) This has the feel of something you read in a book, in which case it would be helpful to have the specific quotation. 2) It also begs the question: is viio -> i common in minor? I don't recall root-position vii (diminished) chords being used much at cadences.

Comment: Actually, my understand is root position `viio` is not usually found in major, but fairly normal in minor. And my sense is I see that born out in real scores.

Comment: an example of root position viio in minor, that comes to mind immediately isn't the best: Bach, 2 part invention in Dm. not the best because it isn't "chords" or Alberti bass figuration.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis I don't find any root position diminished triads at cadences. There are some root position diminished sevenths, but they aren't at cadences, rather they lead to i6 chords. Where do you find the triads?

Comment: OK, but why restrict to cadences only? That isn't the question.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried a survey of scores on this particular point, so this is a bit of guessing. You might not see analysis of, for example `Am: viio/III III`, because it might get labeled as a modulation `C: viio I`. Regardless of the inversion, I'm saying it might simply be analyzed in the relative major.